# Python - Problem importing modules in VirtualEnv

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5, virtualenv

I am trying to import PyQt5 by :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

But it is giving me the Error : Unable to import PyQt5. PyQt5 is definitely installed in the Virtualenv in the location -

```
"c:\users\TM\documents\python projects\pyqt test\env\lib\site-packages"
```

Which I did by - 'py -m pip install pyqt5' while in the (env).

My program is also in the 'pyqt test' folder.

I've installed Python on a new PC and this is the first time I'm having this problem, before I could just import anything in an env without any error.

EDIT: This is my sys.path:

```
['c:\\Users\\TM\\Documents\\Python Projects\\PyQt Test', 
'C:\\Users\\TM\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip', 
'C:\\Users\\TM\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\TM\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\TM\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32', 
'C:\\Users\\TM\0\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Users\\TM\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: to ask the obvious, are you in the virtual env when you try and import?

Comment: Show us the output of `import sys; print(sys.path)`.

Comment: did you activate before installing?

Comment: @JohnGordon I was in the (env) and I have edited my question to provide sys.path.

Comment: @VigneshRajendran Yes I did activate env

Comment: Activate and try this activate
python -m idlelib.idle in CMD it will open the file in this IDLE try running it. it will work if you installed in virtual env